# Disabling ARC in single file in Private Cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm taking a stab at creating a private cocoapod and I've got most of it working. However, my project requires that I disable ARC on a single file in my compile sources.

I found this

[CocoaPods: no_arc a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471424/cocoapods-no-arc-a-single-file)

But it doesnt seem to be solving my issue. I am finding that the files referenced by `no_arc_files` do not show up in the new workspace once i do a `pod install`. Here's what my pod spec looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "MyPrivateProject"
  s.version      = "1.0.1"
  s.summary      = "DataModel Library for Doordash"
  s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/MyPrivateProject.podspec"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author             = { "First Last" => "first.last@gmail.com" }

  s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"

  s.source       = { :git => "https://username@bitbucket.org/username/myproject.git", :tag => "v1.1" }


  non_arc_files   = "MyPrivateProject/Lib/GoogleToolbox/*.{h,m}"

  s.source_files  = "MyPrivateProject", "MyPrivateProject/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.public_header_files = "MyPrivateProject/**/*.h"
  s.exclude_files = non_arc_files

  s.requires_arc = true

  s.dependency "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
  s.dependency "Google-Maps-iOS-SDK", "~> 1.6.0"

  s.subspec 'IgnoreARC' do |ss|
    ss.requires_arc = false
    ss.source_files = non_arc_files
    ss.public_header_files = "MyPrivateProject/Lib/GoogleToolbox/*.h"
  end


end
```

Can anyone give me any tips on what might be going wrong? Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I am attempting to solve my problem (unable to add -fno-objc-arc to a single file) by using a subspec to apply separate configurations to `non_arc_files`.

Comment: Does sub spec require its own Podspec?

Comment: I don't think so - my understanding was that subspec essentially allowed me to alter the configuration options for a sub set of my project -- is that incorrect?

Comment: That makes sense, sorry it's just the first thing I thought of. Maybe add ss.compiler_flags = '-fno-objc-arc' to the subspec?

Comment: Those files are actually not even showing up when i do pod install -- so I am wondering if i am somehow misusing exclude_files or something